# Javascript Exception Errors while setting up cocoonjs launcher app

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception

I'm trying to set up Cocoonjs' launcher app, just to see if some basic functionality that i have in mind will work. But I can't even get my files to show up. When I launch the Cocoonjs app and try to see my files, I keep getting javascript errors and I don't have a clue what to do. The two errors I'm getting are:

> JavaScript Exception(line:6 Tag: 'script'):Reference Error: Can't find variable:$

and

> JavaScript Exception(line:4 File: 'js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js' Tag:'script')TypeError: "undefined" is not an object(evaluating 'f.createElement')

Under the errors it will say for pretty much each file:

> Evaluate JavaScript from script inside file 'lib/easeljs-0.6.1.min.js' (UTF-8)

Is it telling me it's not seeing the jQuery file? Does anyone have any idea how, where or what i do to fix this? Thanks so much!

Comment: where is the jquery-1.10.2.min.js file in your project?

Comment: it's in my js folder. But now im reading that cocoonjs doesnt even need a html file and all js should be in one file? That could definitly be a start to my problems

Comment: check in firebug if the jquery library is loaded..check the url too, the reference error usually happens coz jquery is not loaded, try this `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`

Comment: thanks. I tried that and still the same issue. The answers somewhere  on this page. Its just so far nothing is working.

Comment: http://blog.ludei.com/the-cocoonjs-launcher-app-a-simple-tutorial/

Comment: hey! can't open that blog page, will look into it when I can, have you looked into any sample from [http://cocoonjsservice.ludei.com/cocoonjslaunchersvr/demo-list/](http://cocoonjsservice.ludei.com/cocoonjslaunchersvr/demo-list/) and see how they have done?

Answer (score 1):

ok so for anyone having a similar issue, I found some answers.

First, I had to just get rid of jQuery and do things with normal JS. From what i'm reading around the interweb, CocoonJS doesnt support DOM elements, and jQuery uses them as it starts up? Is that correct? Im not sure but i think that's the gist I'm getting. If there's a way to use jQuery with cocoonjs, I havent found it.

As for the

> > Evaluate JavaScript from script inside file 'lib/easeljs-0.6.1.min.js' (UTF-8)

I think that's just cocoonjs listing what it's done